# Deadletter Automatically with Service Bus trigger in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I need to ensure that if a message fails it automatically goes into the Dead Letter queue when processed within an Azure Function

This doesnt appear to be supported out of the box, or am I missing something?

It can be achieved by setting AutoComplete to false in the host.json option but that introduces other complexities I would rather avoid

I'm using Azure Functions v2

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public async Task MyMethodAsync(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("%AzureTopicName%", "cache-trade-profit", Connection = "event-bus-connection")]
         Message message,  MessageReceiver messageReceiver)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("PRocessing message");        
        throw new Exception("TESTING EXCEPTION");
    }
```

So as you can see here, I am raising an error on purpose

I would expect to see in my log 10 entries for Processing message, I get 1

Configuration:

Im not sure if I have hit the issue that people have said about with host.json config being lost so I use this

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        var services = builder.Services;

        builder.Services.Configure(delegate(ServiceBusOptions options)
        {
            options.PrefetchCount = 10;
            options.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
            options.SessionHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
            options.BatchOptions.MaxMessageCount = 10;
            options.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 10;
            options.SessionHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentSessions = 10;
        });
    }
```

My host.json Service Bus config

```
"extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
        "prefetchCount": 10,
        "messageHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": true,
            "maxConcurrentCalls": 10,
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
        },
        "sessionHandlerOptions": {
            "autoComplete": true,
            "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
            "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
            "maxConcurrentSessions": 10
        },
        "batchOptions": {
            "maxMessageCount": 1000,
            "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
            "autoComplete": true
        }
    }
}
```

My subscription config is here

[image]

Paul

Comment: When a message is failing processing and an exception is thrown, Function should retry it until all attempts are exhausted and the message is moved to the DLQ. What's the behaviour you're experiencing? Could you share your code and configuration (remove secrets)?

Comment: When AutoComplete is true, the message never makes it into the DLQ and just vanishes so that means I have no way of trying it again, or having the messages go to the DLQ for reprocessing

Comment: AutoComplete should do that when the message is successfully processed and no exceptions are thrown. AutoComplete set to false should be used when you want to control the flow. Seeing your code and configuration would help.

Comment: Ok Im just seeing if I can get the code

Comment: I have added config and code I have no idea why this isnt working

Comment: Thank you. "I would expect to see in my log 10 entries for Processing message, I get 1". Do you get a single error and the message is discarded or what happens to the message?  What's the value subscription `MaxDeliveryCount` is set to? And, maybe provide the configuration of your entity (subscription) to see how it's configured as well.

Comment: I will get screenshot of subscription when I am back in the office. The message just disappears not on dlq or normal one

Comment: Ive added subscription config

Comment: It's not there @Paul... the last edit is from Jan 11.

Comment: ok sorry its there now

Comment: Nothing out of ordinary. I'd need the code/repro to see what's going on but the functionality OOTB is to retry the incoming message number of times `MaxDeliveryCount` is set to and then dead-letter it.